# how to view query string parameter of a SSL certificated website which is encrypted using .httaccess

Tags: security, encryption, https, openssl, querystringparameter

could anyone explain how to view the complete URL of a website including query string paramter , if it is encrypted with SSL. Tried wireshark packet capture and keylog method, but it exposed only http requests, i couldnt find query string parameter